# Property 'userForm' does not exist on type 'RootComponent'

Tags: angular, npm, frontend

This is my component class using Angular, for some reason it doesn't compile the first time using `npm start` but when I refresh or save the file again, it's fine and I can view it on my browser. The error I'm getting is

`ERROR in src/app/root/root.component.ts(14,12): error TS2339: Property 'userForm' does not exist on type 'RootComponent'.`

I've looked at similar questions but none of them seem to have a solution to my problem. Here's the class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './root.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./root.component.css']
})
export class RootComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: [''],
        lastName: [''],
        email: [''],
        password: [''],
      });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the variable `userForm`is not defined in your component, so you are trying to to assign a a `FormGoup` in a non existing variable, adding a `userForm: FormGroup;` at the begining of the class should solve de problem:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './root.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./root.component.css']
})
export class RootComponent implements OnInit {
  userForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: [''],
        lastName: [''],
        email: [''],
        password: [''],
      });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define `userForm` in the component before assigning the value